# Dynamic embeddedForm

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm looking to add an embeddedForm dynamically in Symfony 1.4 using Doctrine.

What I'm mainly looking to do is:

1) Only show the relation based on whether or not a checkbox has been ticked

2) If checked, show the embeddedForm

3) Have then the ability to add a new embeddedForm or delete an existing form

I have seen `ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelationsPlugin`, which looks pretty good with los of configuration. The only problem was that `'newFormsInitialCount'=> 1,` means that there is always 1 form as default. I need 0 forms as default and only.

I've also seen a couple of tutorials, but all seem to have at least one relation by default.

For me, the embeddedForm needs to be OPTIONAL, and only display when needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow information based on these links :

- http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/stretching-sfform-with-dynamic-elements-ajax-a-love-story
- http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms#chapter_06_sub_the_form_saving_process

First is about adding "subforms" with ajax, derived from second you could hide the unneeded form fields and toggle them per javascript (e.g. jQuery.toggle())) !